# Angular2 / Nativescript observables

Tags: angular2-nativescript

Can I use angular2`s observables or do I must use nativescripts observables? Because nativescripts observable are not generic its annoying. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use RxJS in a NativeScript with Angular project. RxJS is the same library used in the core Angular framework.

You have options.

Best,